# Does Codeception have an equivalent to PHPUnit's "strict coverage"?

Tags: codeception

When using PHPUnit, you can [annotate a test case](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.specifying-covered-methods) with `@covers SomeClass::someMethod` to ensure that only code inside of that method is recorded as covered when running the test. I like to use this feature because it helps me separate code that was incidentally executed during a test from code that was actually tested.

After using Codeception to implement some acceptance tests for my project, I decided I would rather use it than PHPUnit to run my unit tests. I would like to remove PHPUnit from the project if possible.

I am using Codeception's [Cest](http://codeception.com/docs/05-UnitTests#Cest) format for my unit tests, and the `@covers` and `@codeCoverageIgnore` annotations no longer work. Code coverage reports show executed code outside of the methods specified with `@covers` as covered. Is there any way to mimic that "strict coverage" functionality using Codeception?

**Edit:** I have submitted an [enhancement request](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3409) to the Codeception project's Github.

Comment: Please raise this feature request in https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Comment: @Naktibalda will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that strict coverage was not possible using Cest-format tests when I asked the question. I have implemented it and the pull request has been [merged](https://git.io/viHdN).

For anyone migrating tests from PHPUnit and looking for this feature as I was, this means that a later release of Codeception *should* provide support for `@covers`, `@uses`, `@codeCoverageIgnore`, and other related test annotations.

The current version (`2.2.4` at the time this was written) doesn't support it but `2.2.x-dev` should.